# How do I clean and split up the following string?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a column in my database which stores string in the following format:

```
"['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']"
```

How do I extract the movie genres so I can use them seperately, after extraction I should have the following:

```
g1 = 'Action'  
g2 = 'Adventure'  
g3 = 'Comedy'
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: _How do I extract the movie genres so I can use them seperately_ Why not fix whatever is storing the data in that bizarre (at best) format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. You can split them at every `,` and strip `[] '` off of the word and use tuple unpacking.

```
a="['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']"

g1,g2,g3=[i.strip(" []'") for i in a.split(',')]
```

---

```
print(g1,g2,g3)
# Action Adventure Comedy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like regex:

```
import re
g = "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']"
g1,g2,g3 = re.findall(r"'(\w+)'",g)
print(g1,g2,g3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
inputString = "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']"

# Converting string to list 
res = inputString.strip('][').split(', ') 

g1= res[0]
g2= res[1]
g3= res[2]
```

There are quite a few ways to do this.

1. Using string manipulation as done above.
2. Using `ast.literal_eval()`.
3. Using `json.loads()`.

You can checkout all the examples here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-a-string-representation-of-list-into-list/

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of mangling you can use `json`:

```
import json

src = "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']"
src = src.replace("'",'"')

g = json.loads(src)
g1,g2,g3 = g

print(g1,g2,g3)
```

Output:

```
Action Adventure Comedy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using regex:

```
import re
g = "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Comedy']"
[g1, g2, g3] = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", g)).split(" ")
```